# copy logical volume from one volume group to another

Tags: lvm, aix

I want to copy a logical volume from one volume group to another on AIX. How can I do this? Is `copyvg` the right command?

Comment: Is there a filesystem on the LV? If yes, you're probably best of checking `rsync`. I don't see how copyvg can work here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

check it is `rootvg` otherwise try `exportvg` and `importvg` really it works.

Comment: `exportvg` : «Only a complete volume group can be exported, not individual physical volumes.» And the OP said: "copy logical volume from one volume group to another"

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question — you don't need to (and shouldn't) create a second accoun to do that. But I'm a bit confused, as this doesn't actually seem to solve the problem you originally gave in the question.

Answer (score 3):

In case `vgmerge` doesn't fit your needs, you're to create another volume of equal or bigger size in the destination VG and then simply `dd` from source to destination (using snapshot, as the source, if you like).

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is `cplv`

> "Copies the contents of a logical volume to a new logical volume."

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/index.jsp?topic=/iphcg/cplv.htm